# A-frame with D3 js not able to add the x,y,z-axis coordinate point and scaling not working

Tags: d3.js, graph, aframe

I am confused, how to provide x,y,z-scaling points and few of the points going outside the graph area and main logic is in ***hidden.aframe-scatter-component.js***

code link Link:    [https://plnkr.co/edit/7Nz24nheYv6wehLYzEs1](https://plnkr.co/edit/7Nz24nheYv6wehLYzEs1?p=preview)

[image]

```html
<script src="./hidden.aframe-scatter-component.js"></script>
```

Comment: This question could use an actual explanation of the problem. And a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with emphasis on *minimal*.

Comment: Above code is incomplete and scaling is not working few points are coming outside the graph area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with Your `d3.extent()` in Your `plotData = function (data)`. 
For some reason it does not put "10" in the array, so instead of the range of [0,10] you get smaller values like [0,5.1]. When mapping smaller maxRange in your `scale.linear()`function, You get way too big values.
I've put manually [0,10] in the domains ( as it seems to be the limit of compensation,willWork and totalFI in Your .csv):

```
var zScale = d3.scale.linear()
                       .domain([0,10])
                       .range([zRange[0], zRange[1]]);
```

And it seems to work fine in my [forked plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/wLuztrU2097XtuVubdQL?p=preview), given the fact that most of Your data is values < 5.1
 As suggested, please make a way smaller example using the extent function and check why it's behaving this way. 
 In my fork, You will also find a wScale var or whatever, I needed to get familiar with this d3 stuff.

Comment: hey its working fine need only help on showing points in scale like 1 to 10 for all coordinate

Comment: I'll be home in 3 hours, please specify what help you need, all of them have ranges of 0,10

Comment: I mean showing coordinate point which I highlighted in red box like 1 ,2,3, .. 10

Comment: Oh, You mean adding the axis everywhere, I'll check it out once im home

Comment: @B.V.SBharatKumar updated my plunk, either add them manually like i did, or make o for loop when making the graph and add them dynamically from "-range/2 + i*width/range", like i did manually :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146966/discussion-between-b-v-s-bharat-kumar-and-piotr-adam-milewski).